# Extract value based on another column value python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I display the 'amount' value when 'year' = 5? (Python)

So for year = 5, I want to display the amount-value which is 2

```
   year  amount
0    4    1
1    5    2
2    6    3
```

Comment: _In a list like the one below_ It's a list? Please provide a [mcve], with an unambiguous representation of the data. In any case, this seems like a basic Pandas question, have you done any research?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DataFrame is called `df`:

```
df[df.year==5].amount.item()
```

Comment: or ``df.loc[df.year.eq(5), "amount"].item()``